# Arrange in R for Frequency in Column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for the most common `Start Station Name` in the column. So I used:

```
Top_Start_Station_Name <- df %>%
  count(start_station_name)
```

However, it contains 82 pages of station names and their occurrences. How can I arrange it to have the most 5 station names appear?

Comment: You can arrange by using exactly this dplyr word… `arrange`.

Comment: You want to count the number of times that each station name occurs and then return the names of the five most common?

Comment: Yes rg255, Sorry for any confusing.

Comment: Maybe try `count(start_station_name, sort=TRUE) %>% slice(1:5)`. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you MrFlick. It does work now. Really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: This should give you a plot of the top 5 stations:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(start_station_name = fct_lump(start_station_name, n=5)) %>% 
  count(start_station_name) %>% 
  mutate(start_station_name = fct_reorder(start_station_name, n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(start_station_name, n))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

the `arrange(desc(.))` function composition can sort by counts (named `n`)  in the tbl_df that results from the `count` function:

```
 Top_5_Start_Station_Names <- df %>% 
                          count(start_station_name) %>% # 2 col tbl, first col are names
                          arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
                          .[1:5,1]    # pick first 5 items from first col
```

If you wanted both the names and counts you could use `.[1:5 ]` as the last function. (Only now do I see the more compact and earlier comment by @MrFlick.)